# AES encryption init error

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm trying to set up AES encryption for an application and Eclipse is throwing the following errors:

```
"Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on tokens, ConstructorHeaderName expected instead
    - Syntax error on token "(", < expected
    - Syntax error on tokens, ConstructorHeaderName expected instead"
```

on lines

`enccipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretkey);`

and

`deccipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretkey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));`

Here is my code:

```
private final byte[] salt = new SecureRandom().generateSeed(8);
SecretKeyFactory fact = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(null, salt, 65536, 256);
SecretKey tempsecret = fact.generateSecret(spec);
private SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tempsecret.getEncoded(), "AES");

private Cipher enccipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
enccipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
private final byte[] iv = enccipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();

private Cipher deccipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
deccipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

protected byte[] doEncrypt(String pass){
    return enccipher.doFinal(pass.getBytes());
}
protected String doDecrypt(byte[] ciphertext) {
    return new String (deccipher.doFinal(ciphertext), "UTF8");
}
```

Comment: That should be protected byte[] doEncrypt(String pass){
        return enccipher.doFinal(pass.getBytes());
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Post your code - but my guess is that you're just entering text into the class body (where it says `does not go not here`) instead of inside methods (where it says `code goes here`).

```
public class XYZ {

   // variable and method declarations go here  
   // code does not go here

   public XYZ () {
   // code goes here
   }
}
```

Comment: You're right, I thought it was inside a method, however I was mistaken. Thank you for your answer!